# Accessing /dev/input/events0 file through jni in Android 4.2

Tags: android, c, linux, java-native-interface

I need to port an automation tool from Android 2.3 to Android 4.2 based target. I am trying to get some touch events from `/dev/input/events0` using `open()` system call and then use a `poll()` system call to wait for any changes on its file descriptor.

This works just fine if I write the logic in a C file and run the binary by placing it in `system/bin` directory. poll method returns and I can read the content using `read()` method on the descriptor.

I call these methods using JNI in Android 2.3 based target. It works fine, but only if the app is a part of the system image and the library(native code) exists in `system/lib` directory as a `.so` file.

But now the problem is, the same code is not running in Android 4.2. The `poll()` system call never returns, even if I give a lower timeout value.

One important point to note here is, this same behavior was observed when the library existed as a part of the APK file in Android 2.3 and was run as an installed application.

Also currently I have only quick boot build working, no normal boot. APK/ODEX and `*.so` files is what I have at my disposal.

I am suspecting it is an issue with permissions. Internally android is not giving me access to driver files in 4.2, as application seems to be better sandboxed than it was in 2.3. Ironically, `open()` works just fine, only when I do `poll()`, it is not working.

I need to overcome this problem. Please help.

Here is code snippet:-

```
int i, numread, value, ret, readlen;
struct input_event event;
struct timeval now;
struct timespec tm;
while (run) {
        /* wait for input from any of the input devices(/dev/input/events0) */
        if (poll(input_fds, NUM_DEVICES , -1) < 0) {
                return EVENT_RECORDER_ERROR;
        }
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "EVENT_RECORD",
                "Poll completed");

        for (i = 0; i < NUM_DEVICES; i++) {
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "EVENT_RECORD",
                                                                        "device no %d", i);
                if (input_fds[i].revents & POLLIN) {
                        if (input_fds[i].fd == sockfd)
                                readlen = MAX_DATA_LENGTH;
                        else
                                readlen = sizeof(event);

                        /* read the data here and write it to the output file */
                        numread = read(input_fds[i].fd, buffer, readlen);
                        }
        }
}
```